# Accessing same spreadsheet but show different records, filtered by category in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Good day,

Just want to ask if it is possible to access same google-spreadsheet by different google account and show different records depend on the category or primary key that they have or they belong?

thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can functionally do this, but it isn't neat and creates more problems than it solves. Here's a simple example:

```js
function hideSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Your sheet");

  // Get the user accessing the sheet
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // Match an email. If you're using an array of people, you'll need to loop it.
  if(user != "email@email.com") {

    // If they don't match the test, hide the sheet.
    ss.hideSheet();
  } else {
    ss.showSheet();
}
```

Set an `onOpen()` trigger for the function. The users will need editing rights (which kind of defeats the purpose) or the script won't run. If it's a shared sheet, it will also hide for *you* unless you test for your account, but showing the sheet will *also* show for shared users.

A better solution would be to start a master sheet and `=IMPORTRANGE(url, range)` on slave sheets.

Create a master sheet only you have access to. Title each sheet by region. Create slave sheets titled by the region you want to give to someone else.  In cell A1, use `=IMPORTRANGE("theMasterSheetUrl","New York!A:Z")`. Changing the range value allows you to share only portions of a master spreadsheet, so the New York rep doesn't see the San Francisco, etc. It avoids all the hassle of adding/removing permissions through a script and ensures up to date data on the region they need access to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir @Brian, this is very useful on my project., but how about on the same spreadsheet and same sheet. they gonna access it at the same timer, there is one field that identify their section, ex. 

user1 = "New York"
user2 = "San Francisco"

It is possible sir that on the same spreadsheet and same sheet, user1 can only see the "New York" records, and in the user2 is "San Francisco"?